# is it possible to convert an SVGPath to Lines or access the inner data?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm using SVGPath to load an svg of a simple shape (outline of a human tooth). But now I need to draw a tangent line on a part of the outline. I don't have any information about the lines that make up the SVGPath to determine curvature. Is there a way to retrieve this information, or to convert my SVGPath outline to a Polyline/List?